# How to alter database value?

Tags: android, database

I have a dialog that has 3 buttons (OK, Alterar, Delete) so when i click in Alterar it goes to another activity to alter the values, but i dont know the code to alter it. 
I only know 2, which are .put/.insert and .delete  .
Now what about alter?

2 rows: nome , telefone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, this is an answer to your edit.
Let's say your table containing your rows has the name Person.
Now you want to change the phone number of the person "MrSmith" to 123456789.

First, enter the new values you want to change.

```
// Values to insert
ContentValues dataToInsert = new ContentValues();                          
dataToInsert.put("name", "MrSmith");
dataToInsert.put("phone", 123456789);
```

Maybe you dont need to put the name back in again, it was some time ago i did this. You can try out yourself :)
Now lets insert these into the database!

```
// We want to update the row where the name is "MrSmith"
String where = "id=?";
String[] whereArgs = { "MrSmith" };
```

The ? in where string is replaced with MrSmith when we do db.update(...).
Now SQL knows what row to update and what data it should update it with. Let's commit!

```
// Update table Person where the row name is "MrSmith"  with the values entered
// in ContentValues!
db.update("Person", dataToInsert, where, whereArgs);
```

I hope this helps! Otherwise you need to check out how SQL Statements are done.

Comment: yeah i saw it but the dataToInsert is where my editTexts are, right? what about the "where', what is it about? and whereArgs?

Comment: The where variable decides which row you want to update. The "?" in the where string is replaced by the first element in the whereArgs list, in this case an id

Comment: so i have 2 Rows, how should i put it? i dont have an "id"

Comment: If you would have a where string with multiple conditions, for example: String where = "id=?" AND name=?", then the first ? is replaed by the first element of whereArgs, and the second ? by the second element. Hope this helps

Comment: Edit your question with your row names so I can help you better! Also the name of the table containing these columns and rows

Comment: Yep, just that but, i also want to edit the Phone Number aswell in the same time i edit the name. How to?

Comment: i tried out, it doens't work because i dont have a ID for each contact, so it had to be which Item i clicked in the ListView.

Comment: If you want to change both, just do it in the ContentValues. You dont have to have an ID, that's mostly used for primary keys. The WHERE statement is just for SQL to know what row you want to access, it could be anything. I really cant be anymore specific

Comment: ok, but as when i hit the Alter button in the dialog it sends me to another page so i also need to have the index of the clicked item in the next activity, so check my question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535385/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-clicked-item-into-another-activity)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT Function

public void editdata(int id,String name)
    {
        db.execSQL("update person set name='"+name+"' where id="+id);

```
}
```

Call function

editdata(id,"test");